# Why does hyper require Handler to implement Sync instead of using independent Handlers per thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, hyper

Hyper has the following [example](http://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.9.10/hyper/server/index.html) of a `Handler` that implements `Sync`:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use hyper::server::{Handler, Server, Request, Response};

struct SenderHandler {
    sender: Mutex<Sender<&'static str>>
}

impl Handler for SenderHandler {
    fn handle(&self, req: Request, res: Response) {
        self.sender.lock().unwrap().send("start").unwrap();
    }
}
```

and states that a `Handler` must implement [`Sync`](http://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.9.10/hyper/server/index.html), since `Handler` can be called from different threads.

To me, this sounds like an unnecessary performance penalty. What I would prefer would be to setup one `SenderHandler` per thread, each being independent, which would remove the requirement on implementing `Sync`.

Have I misunderstood Hyper, Rust's type-system or is this not possible?

Comment: As in the supplied example, I would love to remove the `Mutex` protecting the `Sender` since `Sender` is already designed for lock-free intrathread message-passing. All it requires is a `clone` per thread.

Comment: After a few minutes of thinking about it, I tend to agree with you. Cloning handlers would be more powerful, because you were also able to simulate the old behavior by having a single `Arc<OldBehaviorHandler>` in your handler. It's not that easy the other way around... (as far as I can see right now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this actually seems impossible at the moment in Hyper. It is discussed in [issue 248](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/248) and the developer prefers `Sync` over `Clone`:

> We talked through this on IRC. Simple synopsis is that if it were
>   `Clone`, users could easily have state on their handler that they think
>   is modified with each request, but instead, it would have been cloned
>   several times and not modify what they hoped. Instead, it's better
>   force the user to make sure their state is synchronized.

Answer (score 4):

This is a papercut issue.

`Sync` is trivially implemented for any stateless handler; having a `Clone` bound instead would mean having multiple concurrent states evolving independently from one another (with requests being dispatched randomly). I am not even sure there is a guarantee that while *waiting* during the handling of a request the same thread gets invoked with the result.

By using `Sync`, the author forces you to think about what it means to share state across queries (or even intra-query).

---

> As in the supplied example, I would love to remove the Mutex protecting the Sender since Sender is already designed for lock-free intrathread message-passing. All it requires is a clone per thread.

You can have `Sender` implement `Sync` if it is (think it through, obviously), and then remove the `Mutex`.

It also possible, though not too elegant, to have one instance per thread using the [`thread_local!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/) macro, and then a trampoline handler dispatch the work to the thread-local `Sender` upon invocation.

---

Finally, note that hyper is under redesign at the moment; it should move to `Future` which may or may not cause some reconsideration here.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was not aware different threads could be handling various parts of processing of one request, is this always true or does it follow from hyper's design?

Comment: Also, how would I have `Sender` implement `Sync` and what does this entail? I thought the very design of `Sender` prohibits `Sync` and forces user to clone instead.

Comment: @PureW: which `Sender`? I thought this was a type in your code (since there is no qualification), if it's not then you cannot implement `Sync` for it. If it is, then you can implement `Sync` for it, using `unsafe`, if you know what you are doing; you might want to ask on reddit, the users forum or IRC though if this is all alien to you.

Comment: Sorry, the `Sender` is the one in `mpsc`. The full example has a `use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;`